# GitHub auto-merge option isn't showing in pull requests

Tags: github, automerge

According to GitHub's [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/incorporating-changes-from-a-pull-request/automatically-merging-a-pull-request), after enabling "Allow auto-merge" in my repo settings, I should see a button that says "Enable auto-merge" in my pull requests. I do not.

[image]

> 

[image]

I've opened new PRs, toggled the types of merging allowed, and switched my repo visibility to public, but nothing has worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I resolved this by applying a branch protection to the main branch. Pull requests raised after that time now show the "Enable auto-merge" button.

This makes sense because, if the base branch is unprotected, the PR would merge immediately after being raised since status checks typically take at least a couple of seconds to report a "pending" status.

Comment: I have protected the branch, I add some checkbox as well, but the button is still not visible for me. Any idea ,

Comment: I thought I had protection enabled as necessary for auto-merge, but it turns out I had to choose (in the repo Settings) which status checks had to pass in order for the PR to be mergable. Once I did that, the Auto-merge button showed up.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and just want to complement the right answer and make the comprehension easier.

You need to:

- Activate auto-merge in the base branch;
- Protect the base branch checking "Require pull request reviews before merging" or "Require status checks to pass before merging";
- Select which status checks are required in order to merge automatically, as this image shows [image: select status checks]

Then auto-merge option will show: [image: auto merge showing]

Source: [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/incorporating-changes-from-a-pull-request/automatically-merging-a-pull-request)